# Run on iOS 13 device using Xcode without iOS 13

Tags: ios, xcode

Whoops, I upgraded my phone with the iOS 13 beta. I haven't upgraded to Catalina beta on my computer, and I'd rather not.

When I try to run an app on my phone, Xcode 10.3 on my computer running macOS Mojave 10.14.5 is saying

> Could not locate device support files. This phone is running iOS 13.0 which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

App Store isn't showing any newer Xcode, and Preferences > Components > Simulators isn't showing an iOS 13 simulator.

Am I screwed?

Comment: You have to download the Xcode Beta as well. That is not shown in updates. You have to get it directly from the apple member center.

Comment: Install Xcode 11 beta. It works on macOS 10.14.5.

Comment: Thanks! Obviously this is the answer. Feel free to post it as an answer so I can mark it thusly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download the Xcode Beta as well. That is not shown in updates. You have to get it directly from the apple member center. Should work on current Mac OS as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can download iOS 13 developer disk image and add it in Supported Platforms. Then restart Xcode. Works for me.

Comment: you can download from 
https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/tree/master/Developer%20Disk%20Image

Answer (score 0):

You should download the Xcode 11 beta as well from the the Apple developer portal
https://developer.apple.com/download/